# Angular: Using internationalization (i18n) in ngFor

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngfor, ngx-translate

I want traslate a ngFor-loop by using i18n label.

Here is my code:

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```js
name: string;
people: string[];


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name = 'Sam';
    this.people = ['Sam', 'Leo', 'Mark'];
}
```

**mycompoent.component.html**

```html
<!-- Error -->
<div class="myclass">
  <li i18n="@@translate" *ngFor="let person of people">
    <span>{person, select, name {name} other {other}}</span>
  </li>
</div>
<!-- Work -->
<div class="myclass">
  <span i18n="@@translate">{name, select, name {name} other {other}}</span>
</div>
```

**nessage,zh.hant.xlf**

```xml
<trans-unit id="translate" datatype="html">
  <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, name {name} other{} }</source>
  <target>{VAR_SELECT, select, Sam {Trans_Sam} Leo {Trans_Leo} Mark {Trans_Mark} other {Trans_Other} }</target>
</trans-unit>
```

result only get one "Trans_Sam" and get this Error:

```
ERROR Error: Unable to parse ICU expression in "{VAR_SELECT, select, Sam {Trans_Sam} Leo {Trans_Leo} Mark {Trans_Mark} other {Trans_Other}}" message.
```

I know the ngx-traslate but I want to resolve it by i18n label.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just move the i18n out of the ngFor

```
<!-- should work -->
<div class="myclass">
  <li  *ngFor="let person of people">
    <span i18n="@@translate">{person, select, name {name} other {other}}</span>
  </li>
</div>
<!-- Work -->
<div class="myclass">
  <span i18n="@@translate">{name, select, name {name} other {other}}</span>
</div>
```